# MySQL - creating table where column input can be date or date as string

Tags: mysql, sql, date

What is the best way to create a table where a field will be a date. However, the input from the flat files may be formatted mm/dd/yyyy or a date as passed as a string.

Example inputs could be:

12/01/2000

"2000/12/01"

Simply using the code below won't account for the string, correct?

```
CREATE TABLE datetable
(
date DATE NOT NULL
);
```

How do I code for string AND the date?

Comment: The date should be stored in one format YYYY-MM-DD. You should convert all dates in this format during inserting data to db from your csv files.

Comment: Hi Andrej, would you mind helping me with how that would look? Would that look like CREATE TABLE datetable ( date CONVERT(DATE 101) NOT NULL); ?

Comment: How are you going to import data into db?

Comment: LOAD DATA INFILE from a local folder INTO datetable

Comment: In this case I would suggest you to use VARCHAR(10).